# Try except bug check

Tags: python, break, continue

I'm doing a certain online course and I've completed the assignment with this code, but I can still induce a bug with certain inputs, and I can't understand why. I've asked the course mentors (using pseudo code) and they say there's a problem with my try/except statement.

The program should prompt a user for a number, over and over again, returning an error if something non-numeric is entered, with the exception of the string 'done,' in which case it will return the maximum and minimum of all the numbers entered.

Here's the program:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:

    num = input("Enter a number: ")


    if num == 'done': break

    try:  
        float(num)

    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif largest < num:
        largest = num

    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif smallest > num:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

If you enter the following values as input `1 2 3 pk 27 -37 done`, the output is `Max: 3, Min -37.`

It's driving me crazy. I have do idea why this is happening.

Comment: Having a hard time reproducing this, how are you entering in non-numeric values?

Comment: the entries go 1, 2, 3, pk, 27, -37.

any string can go in the place of 'pk'

Comment: forgot to add the 'done' in the inputs

Comment: BTW, it's better to use `except ValueError` than to use a "naked" `except`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting the input to a float, but not retaining that for later checks.

So later on after the except block, Python is doing string comparisons and is comparing the string `"3"` to the string `"27"` and since `'3'` is 'larger' than `'2'` it considers `"3"` larger than "`27`", much like `"b"` is larger than `"aaabbbbzzz"`.

To fix it change this:

```
float(num)
```

to this:

```
num = float(num)
```

Comment: Perfect! Makes so much sense! Learned something about string comparisons because of this post.

Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, it was a tiny error anyone could make. If it helped you can let other people know you've got a good answer by clicking the tick next to my question once its available.